# Bibliography at end of chapter

Tags: biblatex

I want to have a bibliography at the end of each chapter (and later also at the end of the book).

In this MWE this does not work. I expected to have at the end "[1] A B, Test Journal ..."
Bibtex runs with "Process exited normally".

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % load the package

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography_file.bib}
@ARTICLE{myref,
  AUTHOR       = "A B",
  TITLE        = "Test",
  JOURNAL      = "Journal",
  YEAR         = "2019",
  NUMBER       = "1"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography_file.bib} % add a bib-reference file

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

Hello. We cite \cite{myref}

\begin{refsection} % refsection environment
Citation section \thesection: \cite{myref} % collect citations
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography] % print section bibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Bibtex instead of biber?

Comment: @Johannes_B For no special reason. In my editor TeXmaker, bibtex is available by default. Probably I can use biber from there. Is it more complicated?

Comment: No, it is not. Piece of cake: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `refsection`s with BibTeX you need to run BibTeX not only on the main file, but also on helper files for each `refsection`.

Indeed the MWE will produce the warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(biblatex)                refsectbibtex
(biblatex)                refsectbibtex1-blx
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

On a first run. So you don't only run BibTeX on `refsectbibtex` but also on `refsectbibtex1-blx` (and similarly for other refsections).

The normal compilation order

```
latex <file>
bibtex <file>
latex <file>
latex <file>
```

thus becomes

```
latex <file>
bibtex <file>
bibtex <file>1-blx
...
bibtex <file>n-blx
latex <file>
latex <file>
```

where `n` is the number of `refsection`s.

---

If you use Biber instead of BibTeX there is no need for additional Biber runs, you can have arbitrarily many `refsection`s and still compile with

```
latex <file>
biber <file>
latex <file>
latex <file>
```

Just change `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,` and run Biber instead of BibTeX ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) can help you with your editor).

Since some advanced `biblatex` features are only available with Biber, switching to Biber would be the preferred way to resolve this issue.